# Lua xml library with XML schema validation

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, lua

I'm looking for a lua library for parsing XML which can also validate the XML using a schema. Does something like that exist? I can;t seem to find it.

Comment: What kind of schema are you looking to validate with?

Comment: I want to validate against an XSD schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no lib fulfilling your requirements. If you can't remove the Schema requirement, your best option is doing the Schema validation in C/C++ (or java, if you are using luaj). Once that is done, you may use luaexpat for the parsing in Lua or just parse it with the other lib and pass the results to Lua - for example transformed into a Lua table.

Comment: It seems that there are no other options.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a minimalistic binding to Xerces-C++, which can validate xml: https://github.com/d-led/xerceslua
It has been started in order to be able to validate, while the processing is done using pugixml and the binding https://github.com/d-led/pugilua

Answer (score 1):

Expat is usually the best XML parser;
The lua bindings are quite good.
http://matthewwild.co.uk/projects/luaexpat/

Comment: -1: bartvdl asked for an XML parser that does schema validation. Expat does not.

Comment: true; but it is the most commonly used XML parser for lua. I don't know of any pre-existing bindings to a validating XML parser: so rolling your own in lua post-parsing might be an easier option than writing bindings

Comment: Writing bindings is easy, especially with SWIG or Luabind. Even if you code it by hand, it's trivial compared to doing schema validation for either of the main schema languages.

Comment: I disagree; writing a bindings to an XML parser (due to their reliance on callbacks; and the creation of large+complex lua side data structures) requires knowing much about the C api; and is probably best done by hand rather than by automated tools.

Comment: Writing a schema validator requires reading and understanding that particular schema syntax. The libXML2 people haven't even gotten around to making a functioning XSD validator, in part because the spec itself may not fully specify everything. Learning the Lua C API is trivial; writing an XSD validator is not. There's a difference between doing some basic checks of XML to see if it is what you think it is and validating against a _schema_ language.

Comment: I suppose I went on the assumption that he could just create validation functions for just schema hes using; rather than a general purpose solution.

Comment: I was already looking at Expat, but it doesn't have schema validation.